# Display message in textbox instead of messagebox

Tags: c#

```
MessageBox.Show("To: " + tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint + "\r\n\r\n" 
        + "From: " + tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint + "\r\n\r\n" 
        + encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
```

This is the code which is showing message from client to server in a messagebox. i want to display the information in a textbox instead of a messageBox. what should now be the code like?

Comment: *message from client to server* what does this means?

Comment: To display a message in a textbox, set its [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property to a string specifying the content to be displayed. Surely that isn't the whole question?

Comment: through socket connection I am connecting clients with server and sending data from clients to server.

Comment: Where is your TextBox displayed?

Comment: in the server form and i am making this changes in server desktop application c#

Comment: Are you asking us how to change the behavior of the desktop application by modifying code on the server?

Comment: I have corrected. so guys no need to comment anymore thanks btw.